Should data be transformed for NMDS?
I am looking at species count data. Due to large counts of certain species, I initially fourth root transformed the data. However when using vegan::metaMDS-Bray Curtis distance, the stress value for the data is a little over 0.2. Its not much, but I understand that stress values greater than 0.2 are suspicious. However when i use non-transformed data, the stress is less than 0.2.
I am worried this will than impact species scores when plotting if nmds is using untransformed data, and then it won't match PERMANOVA or ANOSIM results either which uses the transformed data.
Is using untransformed data for NMDS alright? Will this cause problems comparing other multivariate tests?
